# extra white space below the footer

Tags: html, css

Below the footer I see additional white space....
how to remove the additional white space....
i reduced the height of the container but even though its not working....
how to fix it.....

providing my fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/h8J4p/embedded/result/

```
<div class="footer">
       <!-- <p>&copy; Company 2012</p>-->
       <p>Copyright© www.defie.co. All rights reserved.</p>

      </div>
```

Comment: You can start by looking at the related questions, or using google. I'll help you out by suggesting looking at 'css div margin'

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/
But you'll have to change your layout `div.row-fluid marketing` and `div.footer` must be wrapped and use the technique on their parent wraper.

Comment: Not enough information to support you. Please, provide your full code, the browser used and a comparison with what you want.

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you update in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h8J4p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to get rid of the extra padding and margin that the body have in default by using the following:

```
body {padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Secondly, you need to remove the entity that @Sport Billy pointed out ​
If you still have a problem then check the previous element. you might have `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom` in the last element

if non of that worked, use `position:relative;` and position the element properly. but use that as a last choice.

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you update in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h8J4p

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h8J4p/2/ you also might want to consult http://validator.w3.org/ you have some errors!

Answer (score 0):

There is some whitespace which is converted to an entity `&#8203;` below the javascript includes after the footer. Try removing it.

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you update in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h8J4p

Answer (score 0):

the best solutions for all your css files...with this wildcard you will reset all margins and paddings to zero

```
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```